# Entity Framework and SharePoint

Tags: development

We have created some user controls which interact with the database using the entity framework. My question is how to use these controls in SharePoint. Do we have to copy the .edmx file to the /virtualdirectories/site folder?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The .edmx file is only used within the source. It's compiled with the Entity Model Code Generator Tool which creates the necessary classes. If you build a class library using the Entity Framework all you need to do is reference the output assembly in your SharePoint project. Or you can add an entity data model to your SharePoint project and use it as normal.

Comment: I m Getting this error after adding .edmx file and add the connection string in web.config
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Comment: Its working fine now, just add <trust level="Full" /> inside <system.web>

Comment: or add a custom CAS policy to your WSP

Comment: Or sign the assembly and install to the GAC